Add-Migration command failing with error Entity Framework package is not installed in project while using .NET Core
My question is I dont understand why I cannot run add-migration without having Entity Framework installed when I have all core items installed and do not target Entity Framework at all.
Details:
Every project in my solution is target .Net 8 and has no package references to Entity Framework, only core. However when I try doing add-migration its telling me I cannot do that as I don't have Entity Framework package installed. I don't understand why this is because I have another solution built the exact same way and there I am able to do add-migration without having Entity Framework installed.
Here is the command I am ruuning and the output that it is giving me:
PM> add-migration newMigration


The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data'.

PM> add-migration newMigration -ProjectName UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data -StartupProjectName UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Api


The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data'.

Here is my .csproj file for my Data project, which is where the migrations and DbContext exist:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Can you please share the full [mre]?

Also can you please share the .csproj for UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Api?

One possibility for this error - In the Package Manager Console, there is a dropdown for 'Default Project'. If this is set incorrectly, you will get The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'x'. Change the dropdown to your EF project and all is good again.

Do you have EF and EF SqlServer packages installed on your Domain or Data project?

Your UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Api must have a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.

Your problem is that you included the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in the Data project.
You should include it in the Api project.
This package in particular isn't inherited like other packages, you must namely add it in the startup project.
So your UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Api.csproj file must contain these lines:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

That should solve your problem.

Anyway, this is usually the code I run to create migration from shell, with few notes I keep in mind to avoid errors I usually have:
dotnet ef migrations add %migration_name% -p %path_to_dbcontext_project% -s %path_to_startup_project%

migration_name: each migration name should be unique.
path_to_dbcontext_project: the project where db contexts live and migrations should be made.
This project must use package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, depending on what db engine/server you're trying to use and generate migration for. Some generated code might depends on it.
Did you make sure you included that package in UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain or UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data? I also encourage you add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package to UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain project anyway.
so your UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain.csproj should contain these lines:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

and the UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data.csproj should contain (it does):
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Domain.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

path_to_startup_project: like a console or asp project.

This project must include/reference the db context project where migration will be generated.
It must also include the nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design as I said in the beginning.

So your Api project file should have these lines:
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data\UCMS_Surrogates_Rewrite.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


You should also consider:

you can't use a lower version of dotnet-ef to generate a migration for higher versions of EFCore. So looking at your versions, make sure you're not using dotnet-ef 6, but 7 or higher.

